# Session timeout with Filter in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, session, iframe, filter, session-timeout

I'm trying to implement Session timeout logic in Spring Boot project with Filter.

1. The filter intercepts every request and checks whether the session is new
2. If the session is timed out, it should redirect to login page.
3. Since there is an iFrame, the redirection is happening inside iframe. how to redirect main page to login page?

Here is the code below:

```
        <body>
        <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle menu-submenu"
            role="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
            target="basefrm"
            th:attr="href='#'+${submenu.shortCode}, title=${submenu.title}">

        <iframe
            class="embed-responsive-item justify-content justify-content-center "
            height="100%"
            width="100%"
            id="basefrm"
            name="basefrm"
            scrolling="overflow-x:no ;overflow-y:no"
            frameborder="0"
            allowTransparency="false"
            style="height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </body>

@WebFilter("/*")
@Order(1)
public class TransactionFilter extends HttpFilter {
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;   
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        
        if(session !=null && !session.isNew() && session.getAttribute("login") != null) {
            if(req.getRequestURI().equalsIgnoreCase(req.getContextPath()+"/")) {
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/loginpage.html");
            }
            else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);              
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.debug("session timed out!");
            session = req.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("login", true);
            
            logger.debug("path:{}"+req.getContextPath());
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/loginpage.html");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: yes. I used javascript to re-route the user to login page in case of session expiry.

Comment: can you please share the solution.

Comment: everytime user presses key or moves the mouse, you reset the JavaScript timer. when the Javascript timer crosses the session timeout limit, user should be redirected to home page where he is asked to login again. Or you can even provide warning or pop up before session is expired before 30-60 seconds.